# Why the text before Ajax call is not display?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, synchronization

```
function pdfToImgExec(file, IsfirstLogging, folder, round) {
  alert(file);
  var postString = file + '&' + IsfirstLogging + '&' + folder + '&' + round;
  var errorMsg = (folder == 'Incoming' ? '<p>error in incoming folder</p>' : '<p>error in other folder</p>');
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    url: "pdfToImgExec.php",
    data: {
      "data": postString
    },
    dataType: "html",
    beforeSend: function () {
      alert(file + 'a');
      $('#pdfToImgResult').html('<p>Converting' + file + ', Please wait......</p>');
    },
    success: function (data) {
      if(data == '1') {
        $('#pdfToImgResult').html('<p>Complete convert ' + file + '</p>');
      } else if(round < 4) {
        $('#pdfToImgResult').html('<p>Fail to convert ， retry ' + round + ' round <img src="loading.gif" height="20" width="20"/></p>');
        round++;
        pdfToImgExec(file, 'false', folder, round);
      } else {
        folder == 'Incoming' ? tempFailIncomingFiles.push(file) : tempFailResultFiles.push(file);
      }
    },
    error: function (x, t, m) {
      $('#pdfToImgResult').html(errorMsg);
      alert(t);
      releaseBtn();
    }
  });
}
```

The problem of this ajax call is I can alert the (file + 'a') in the beforeSend function , but the

```
$('#pdfToImgResult').html('<p>Converting' + file + ', Please wait......</p>');
```

is not working, it will not display anything but only jumped to the

```
$('#pdfToImgResult').html('<p>Complete convert ' + file + '</p>');
```

after the ajax call is finished.

Is it due to `async:false`? How to fix the problem ? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using `async: false,`, so the function blocks until the request is complete, preventing a redraw until everything is done.

You seem to be all set up with callbacks, so there doesn't seem to be any reason to make a blocking xhr request. Just remove the `async: false,`, and you should be all set.

---

Here's a quick example of how to deal with asynchronous code. I've removed most of your code to keep it brief.

```
 // --------------------------------new parameter-------------v
function pdfToImgExec(file, IsfirstLogging, folder, round, callback) {
  // your code...
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
//  async: false,  // Remove this line! 
    url: "pdfToImgExec.php",
    data: {
      "data": postString
    },
    dataType: "html",
    beforeSend: function () {
      $('#pdfToImgResult').html('<p>Converting' + file + ', Please wait......</p>');
    },
    success: function (data) {
      // your code...

      // Invoke the callback, passing it the data if needed
      callback(data)
    },
    error: function (x, t, m) {
      // your code;
    }
  });
}
```

When you call `pdftoImgExec`, pass a function as the last parameter that will be invoked when the response is complete. That function is where your code resumes.

```
pdfToImgExec(..., ..., ..., ..., function(data) {
    // resume your code here.
    alert(data);
})
```

Comment: thx for answering, I have put the display statement in beforeSend function and I have tried the alert popup, it is working. Only the statement to change html element is not working

Comment: @user782104: The `alert()` doesn't require a redraw of the page in order to display. Updating the `.html()` content of an element does. You're blocking the redraw from happening until the function is complete.

Comment: async: false is needed to maintain the order of the program.. Why it block the html() as I have put it in BeforeSend already?